# Is it possible to create an Android application that works alongside Google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am looking to potentially build an Android application that would work alongside Google maps and would require that there is currently navigation running with Google maps. This Android application would really just need to pull the navigation data (the route that is in progress, it would not need turn-by-turn) from Google maps. Does anyone know if this is possible/doable?

I have a couple other ideas so this is not necessarily the be-all, end-all, but if this is doable, I think it would be the best implementation for the users.

I am just looking for some general ideas, any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Have a look at [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

Comment: I haven't looked too in-depth into their API but I would think that you would only be able to grab navigation data from an instance of Google maps within the external application.